# How to fetch Web intelligence report tab metadata i.e. columns?

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I want to fetch SAP BO4 Web intelligence Report Tab Columns information.

I tried fetching this information in Java using -

```
DataProviders dps = reportInstance.getDataProviders();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < dps.getCount(); ii++) {
        com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.DataProvider dp = dps.getItem(ii);
        int recCount = dp.getFlowCount();
        try {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < recCount; iii++) {

                try {
                    Recordset recordSet = dp.getResult(iii);
                    recordSet.first();
                    boolean hasNext = recordSet.isFirst();
            while (hasNext) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < recordSet.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            columns.add(recordSet.getColumnName(j));
```

But `reportInstance.getDataProviders()` returns me dataproviders of all the Report Tabs in a Report Document but I am interested to find out dataproviders in a single Report Tab.

Can I fetch it using SQL queries using CI_InfoObjects etc.?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for which DataProviders are available in that report tab, or are you looking for which DataProviders are in use on that tab?

Comment: I am looking for which data providers are in use on that tab. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Data providers are not bound to individual reports (tabs) but to a document as a whole. Thus, you cannot determine the usage of your data provider that way.

Rather, you'll need to look at the `ReportMap` to see how the document is built:

> The ReportMap interface exposes the document structure. The root level
>   contains the name of the report sheets and the leaves are associated
>   to sections and sub sections. This model is exposed as a tree.

Usage of your data provider can either be a universe object used directly, but also a variable or formula that contains a universe object retrieved by the data provider (or a variable referencing a variable …).

Also keep in mind that the Java Report Engine SDK is deprecated in favour of the REST SDK. Have a look at the [Object Model Diagram](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4_rebean_omd.pdf) to see which part of the SDK is deprecated as of BI 4.0.

You can find more information regarding the REST SDK on the [Web Intelligence SDK](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-37512) page.